# Update volume size dynamically from inside a POD

Tags: docker, kubernetes, volume, kubernetes-volume, persistent-volumes

I was wondering how I could dynamically **create and then mount new volumes from inside a pod ?** **At runtime !**

I have to download a lot of files with very different sizes and would like the storage to adapt to my needs...

---

**Use case example :**
*There is a decompression step. But I don't know how much will be decompressed before its completed.*
If I could allocate some more memory at runtime It would not end with a DiskFull error...

I can mount an initial volume at pod startup, then either I find a way to update this volume size or at least mount a new one in the same pod !

Any ideas are welcome
Thx

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you could create bucket (aws s3 for example) and store your data there (create simple app to make upload), thus, you don’t need to care with disk full error

Comment: Thx for you answer. The problem with this solution is that I must work on the files before uploading them elsewhere. For instance some of them must be uncompressed. I only use S3 for the final upload when the file is ready but still need some local storage capacity while working on the files.